# Where is the atom style sheet in directory?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to add some modifications to my Atom style sheet, but I can't find where Atom is installed. I'm using ubuntu 16. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just open up the stylesheet from the command palette? The full command name is `Application: Open Your Stylesheet`. You can open up the command palette with `Ctrl+Shift+P` on windows/linux or `Command+Shift+P` on Mac in case you didn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom's menu bar -> Edit -> Stylesheet ...

Answer (score 2):

`styles.less` should be in the `~/.atom` directory, as well as Atom packages, the Keymap and other configuration files. The binary files for Atom should be in `/usr/bin/` however.